# ubuntu home folder add items

Tags: 14.04, home-directory

I have a recently installed Ubuntu system (14.04 LTS).  On my old system the home folder showed a "file system" option which allowed me to get at all the folders in the root directory.  However, in my new system that option is not there. How do I revise my home folder so as to get access to these other folders and files?

Comment: It might be called computer...?

Comment: @Tim it is indeed called `Computer` now. Do post that as answer.

Comment: can you post the screen shot, that what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Weird that it is not there, maybe you have removed it by mistake?

Anyway,

1. Open your home folder.
2. Give Ctrl+L.
3. On the line-edit that appeared, remove everything and just place a `/` in it and then press enter.
4. You are now on your root directory. Bookmark this folder and it will now appear on your left.

Comment: Thank you -- you know what -- it turned up under the bookmark "computer".  So I am set.  But I am very glad to know this trick.

Comment: Doesn't the "computer" bookmark lead you there as well? (as others have mentioned)